# How to get rounded corners in twitter-bootstrap3's container-fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to join together two rows that have different colors inside a `container-fluid` and use rounded-corners for the whole container. I have tried to change the value of the `border-radius` parameter to 10px but this does not work. Is there a way to update the container-fluid class to have rounded corners?

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border-radius: 10px">
    <div class="row bg-warning h4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-info">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No space between the rows here http://www.bootply.com/1b1KxBeSRN

Comment: It looks like it is because I have h4 class in the upper row

Comment: OK, so the h4 class is adding a margin then.

Comment: Great, will fix that. How could I get rounded corners for the container?

Comment: Google css3 rounded corners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Remove the `h4` class for joining the container

CSS:

```
        .top {
            border-top-left-radius:50px;
            border-top-right-radius:50px;
        }
        .bottom {
            border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
            border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
        }

.bg-warning{
    background-color:red;    
}
.bg-info{
    background-color:yellow; 
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div style="height:100px" class="row top bg-warning">

</div>
<div style="height:100px"  class="row bottom bg-info">
    ...
</div>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ypvsgqrL/1/)